# Can't use TextMate git bundle since I installed rbenv

Tags: macos, git, textmate, rbenv

Since I installed rbenv on my Mac OSX, and deleted the original ruby version, I'm not able to use the TextMate GIT bundle.

I get this error:

```
 env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

looks like I lost some reference in my environment variables. However, my rbenv global version looks set up ok. Can anyone help?

Comment: Removed the `ruby` that ships with Mac OS X? This sounds like a very bad idea. Maybe there's a reason it ships with OS X, right?

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to reinstall your system Ruby. See: https://superuser.com/questions/171433/is-it-possible-to-reinstall-fix-mac-os-xs-system-ruby-without-doing-a-complete

If you are using Textmate 2 and `rbenv`, configure it properly: [Configure Textmate 2 for rbenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300711/configure-textmate-2-for-rbenv)