# Configure Textmate 2 for rbenv

Tags: textmate2

What is the best way to setup [Textmate 2](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/textmate-2-0-alpha/) to use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/#readme)?

I read a [Textmate mailing list thread about setting up rbenv](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.editors.textmate.general/34552/match=rbenv) but haven't found the right solution yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update your `~/.tm_properties` to include:

```
TM_RUBY = "$HOME/.rbenv/shims/ruby"
PATH = "$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Thanks to uberfork for this helpful article: [Integrate rbenv with Textmate](http://uberfork.com/post/12280974742/integrate-rbenv-with-textmate).

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 6):

The answers supplied here didn't work for me. Here's what did:

1. Preferences -> Variables
2. add this to the front of `PATH`: `$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:`
3. set `TM_RUBY` to this: `$HOME/.rbenv/shims/ruby`
4. populate `RBENV_VERSION` with your version. example: `2.1.0-preview1`
5. (and make sure the checkboxes for each of those variables are selected)

Answer (score 3):

For me adding `/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims` to TextMate's `PATH` variable did the trick.

`PATH` TextMate variable looks like this `/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims:$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to supplement all answers above - if you would like to use different ruby version per project just create a new `.tm_properites` file inside root of the project with the correct `RBENV_VERSION` variable.

Comment: "above" means nothing when the answers can be sorted in a number of ways