# How do I get rbenv and textmate to work together?

Tags: ruby, textmate, rbenv

I tried to trouble-shoot this problem, and found "[Configure Textmate 2 for rbenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300711/configure-textmate-2-for-rbenv)".

However, when I try implementing the solution using multiple versions of Textmate Shell variables:

```
version1 of PATH= $PATH:$HOME/.rbenv/bin
version2 of PATH= $HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
version3 of PATH= $PATH:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin

TM_RUBY=     /usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims/ruby
```

I get the following error:

```
env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

I installed rbenv with brew and `which rbenv`
gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/rbenv
```

`which ruby` gives:

```
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims/ruby
```

I have a `require` in my code, if that changes things. I was told it might.
What shell variables are recommended? What added information would be helpful?

Comment: @thetinman thanks for the edit, much clearer.

Comment: It's not necessary to thank us for edits. We do it as a community service.

Answer (score 3):

I found my solution:

```
PATH= $PATH:$HOME/.rbenv/bin
TM_RUBY= /usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims/ruby
PATH = /opt/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin
```

an interesting note, when the previous posted Path was incorrect, I could not create new files in textmate.