# Require 'mysql' fails in Textmate ruby script but works in irb in Terminal

Tags: mysql, ruby, textmate

When I run my ruby script simply with

```
require 'mysql'
```

in text mate it fails with the following error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file — mysql

method require  in kernel_require.rb at line 54
method require  in kernel_require.rb at line 54
method <main>   in Test.rb at line 1
```

However, if I run it through irb in terminal, require 'mysql' returns a true and I am able to create my connection and query my database.

Please tell me why my textmate script cannot load the mysql gem but irb in terminal can.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

When I run gem env in terminal I get this:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
- RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/(useraccount)/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/(useraccount)/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/(useraccount)/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/(useraccount)/.gem/specs
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-darwin-14
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/(useraccount)/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
 - /Users/(useraccount)/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:
 - /Users/(useraccount)/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin
 - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec
 - /Users/(useraccount)/.rbenv/shims
 - /usr/local/bin
 - /usr/bin
 - /bin
 - /usr/sbin
 - /sbin
 - /Users/(useraccount)/.rvm/bin
```

And when I run gem env in text mate as a shell script I get this:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 481) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/(useraccount)/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0
     - /Users/(useraccount)/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/(useraccount)/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Textmate is using the wrong ruby. Try the instructions from this SO post: [Configure Textmate 2 for rbenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300711/configure-textmate-2-for-rbenv)